# Can a Makefile execute code ONLY when an error has occurred?

Tags: makefile

In my Makefile, I have some code that checks for network connectivity. This code takes a decent amount of time to run and I would only like to run it if another target fails to build.

## Current Makefile

```
all: files network
    # compile files

files:
    # get files from network resources

network:
    # check for network connectivity
    # echo and return an error if it's not available
```

Execution Order:

```
if not network:
    # exit with error
if not files:
    # exit with error
if not all:
    # exit with error
```

## Desired Makefile

In the above example, I would like the `network` target to be "made", only if the `files` target fails to get "made".

Execution Order:

```
if not files:
    if not network:
        # exit with error
if not all:
    # exit with error
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `network` as a separate target?

Comment: @Beta, it wouldn't necessarily have to be.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Recursive make is your friend here I'm afraid.

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    ${MAKE} files || ${MAKE} network
```

If `make files` succeeds, your work is done and the exit code is success. On failure, the exit code is that for `make network`.

Comment: Very useful answer, i personnally added the --no-print-directory option to the first make to avoid the annoying 'entering directory' message