# Can GNU make execute a rule whenever an error occurs?

Tags: error-handling, makefile, gnu-make, dmake

This is slightly different from [Can a Makefile execute code ONLY when an error has occurred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569228/can-a-makefile-execute-code-only-when-an-error-has-occurred).

I'd like a rule or special target that is made whenever an error occurs (independent of the given target; without changing the rule for every target as the other answer seems to imply with the || operator).

In [dmake](http://www.openoffice.org/tools/dmake/dmake_4.6.html) there is *special target* **.ERROR** that *is executed whenever an error condition is detected*. Is there a similar thing with GNU make?

(I'm still using GNU make 3.81, but I didn't find anything in the documentation of the new GNU make 4.0 either)

Comment: No, GNU make does not support this.  You can do it if you use recursion to wrap the "main" make and then run a command if it fails, but that's about it.

Answer (score 26):

Gnu doesn't support it explicitly, but there's ways to hack almost anything.  Make returns 1 if any of the makes fail.  This means that you could, on the command line, rerun make with your error rule if the first make failed:

```
make || make error_targ
```

Of course, I'll assume you just want to put the added complexity within the makefile itself.  If this is the case, you can create a recursive make file:

```
all: 
     $(MAKE) normal_targ || $(MAKE) error_targ

normal_targ:
      ... normal make rules ...

error_targ:
      ... other make rules ...
```

This will cause the makefile to try to build normal_targ, and iff it fails, it will run error_targ.  It makes it a bit harder to read the makefile for the inexperienced, but it puts all the logic in one place.

Comment: How can I get the error code/message from `normal_targ` so that `error_targ` could display some custom error message containing a description of the error?

Comment: This is simply genius

Comment: @JHH Maybe you can do this by using shell `$?` variable, when make fails it returns an error code on this variable so you could do a thing like that `$(MAKE) normal_targ || echo $$? && $(MAKE) error_targ` (this would just print the error value but you can use this value to print a custom message)