# Define "continue if error" policy directly in target dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here's a simple Makefile with 4 targets (`a`, `b`, `c` and `all`). Target `b` can fail (represented here with `exit 1`).

```
a:
    echo "a"

b:
    exit 1

c:
    echo "c"

all: a b c
```

When running `make all`, `c` is never printed as `b` fails and target `c` is consequently not run. But in my particular case, I want `c` to be run, even if `b` fails.

I'm wondering if there is a way to define the "continue if error" policy **directly** inside the dependencies of target `all`.

I know that the desired behaviour can be reached by :

- running `make -i all` (`--ignore-errors`) or `make -k all` (`--keep-going`)
- using a ["recursive" make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118020/can-gnu-make-execute-a-rule-whenever-an-error-occurs)
- prefixing failing command in `b` with `-` (like `-exit 1`)
- running tasks separately with `make a; make b || make c`

but all of these options implies to modify targets `a`, `b` or `c`, or modify the way `make all` is called.

Is there a way to have the expected behaviour by **just modifying** the `all` target dependencies (something like `all: a -b c`, but that definition does not work, obviously)?

**Additional requirement** : `make all` should return with exit code 1 if `b` fails, even if `c` target succeeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run all recipes of `a, -b, c` even if the `-<something>` ones fail you can use a pattern rule for `-<something>` targets:

```
a c:
    @echo "$@"

b:
    @echo "$@"; exit 1

all: a -b c

-%:
    -@$(MAKE) $*
```

Demo (with `--no-print-directory` for simpler output):

```
$ make --no-print-directory all
a
b
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'b' failed
make[1]: *** [b] Error 1
Makefile:10: recipe for target '-b' failed
make: [-b] Error 2 (ignored)
c
```

But if you also want to "*remember*" their exit status, things are a bit more difficult. We need to store the exit status somewhere, for instance in a file and reuse it for the `all` recipe:

```
a c:
    @echo "$@"

b:
    @echo "$@"; exit 1

all: a -b c
    @exit_status=`cat b_exit_status`; exit $$exit_status

-%:
    -@$(MAKE) $*; echo "$$?" > $*_exit_status
```

Demo:

```
$ make --no-print-directory all
a
b
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'b' failed
make[1]: *** [b] Error 1
c
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Hard-wiring the name of the potentially failing target in the recipe of `all` is not very elegant. But it should be quite easy to solve:

```
a b c:
    @echo "$@"

d:
    @echo "$@"; exit 1

all: a -b c -d
    @for f in $(patsubst -%,%_exit_status,$(filter -%,$^)); do \
        tmp=`cat $$f`; \
        printf '%s: %s\n' "$$f" "$$tmp"; \
        if [ "$$tmp" -ne 0 ]; then exit $$tmp; fi; \
    done

-%:
    -@$(MAKE) $*; echo "$$?" > $*_exit_status

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *_exit_status
```

Demo:

```
$ make --no-print-directory all
a
b
c
d
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'd' failed
make[1]: *** [d] Error 1
b_exit_status: 0
d_exit_status: 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the well-explained answer. Another question (though not related) : if I have multiple `Makefile` in my current folder, or if I have to pass parameters to the `Makefile`, how could I specify these parameters in `$(MAKE)` call?

Comment: `make -f <file> VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE2...`: `-f <file>` tells make that the Makefile to use is `<file>` and `VAR1=VALUE1` defines make variable `VAR1` with value `VALUE1`.

Comment: My question was unclear, sorry, in fact I'm already running `make -f <file> VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE2`. But when running `$(MAKE)` inside the `Makefile`, the command run is `make` without the parameters I used to run the initial `make`. I was wondering if there is a simple way to propagate those parameters to `$(MAKE)`.

Comment: This is a very different question and it is difficult to answer in a comment. You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: The original parameters won't appear on the command-line where the sub-make is run. The sub-make will know of them however. They are passed by other means. (Shared memory? Environment variables? Who cares... if you do, have a look at [the secution about recursion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion) in the manual.)

Answer (score 0):

While you can't transmit parameters through prerequisite names (or at least only if you change the prerequisites completely), you could employ target-specific variables. But the solution isn't exactly pretty, with an additional variable leading every recipe line:

```
CIE_DASH = $(if $(filter $@,$(CONTINUE_SET)),-)

all: a b c
all: CONTINUE_SET += b

a: 
    $(CIE_DASH)echo "a"

b: CONTINUE_SET += e
b: e 
    $(CIE_DASH)exit 1

e:
    $(CIE_DASH)exit 1
c:
    $(CIE_DASH)echo "c"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case, why `exit 1` is not the only line that should be prefixed by `$(CIE_DASH)`? Because only `b` target can fail. Also, why `e` is needed? Finally, with this solution, how could I capture exit code of `b` and propagate it to `c` (see the additional requirement in my question)?

Comment: I just put `$(CIE_DASH)` in front of everything because you don't know in advance if some day you're going to add `a` or `c` to the `CONTINUE_SET`. `e` isn't needed, I just wanted to demonstrate that this is a hierarchical method to suppress exit on error - the programmer writing the `all` target may be unaware of the things happening down below `b`.

Comment: Propagation to `c` is impossible/unreliable because make is free to decide on the order of evaluation of independent targets. Propagating to the top level rule... honestly I think this going to get even uglier and you can't use my solution then because the dash forces make to ignore the return code - no way to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Got the idea, it's clever and it may be useful in some cases. But in the specific case I explained, this solution is similar to my 3rd point : prefixing failing command in `b` with `-` (like `-exit 1`), because I know that only `b` can fail in my example. So there is no need here to use `CONTINUE_SET`, nor prefixing all lines by `CIE_DASH`.