# How to run a post build script in CMAKE, regardless if any object fails?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to generate a compiler error and warning report post-build. This is all in a CMake Environment.

So I created a script, and tied to executable post-build.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
   COMMAND python.exe genReport.py"
)
```

however this won't execute if not all STATIC Librarys are generated, because then the executable can't link them.

So I thought now I needed to create call same custom command post-build per library.

However, we also create objects before Libraries, and objects can't have a post build command.

All I'm trying to do is always run a script at the end of a make all. Whether executable is built, or any library fails, or any object fails to compile.

Is there a way to always run a post build script?

Comment: I don't think that CMake supports running command on the build stage even if another command fails. E.g. [Make doesn't support that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118020/can-gnu-make-execute-a-rule-whenever-an-error-occurs). Just create your own script, which internally executes `make` and then calls `python.exe genReport.py`.

Comment: didn't seem to work, am i doing this right?

  add_custom_target(run
      COMMAND make -j
      COMMAND  python.exe genReport.py
  )

Comment: No, I mean a non-CMake script, e.g. a shell one, or a python. And instead of running `make` for build the project, you could run that additional script.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, that's an acceptable answer. Thanks for identifying cmake limitation, I've moved forward with a batchscript to launch make with stderr redirected to a text file, and follow up summarizing python script