# How to delete the target file in case of error in Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

In the following example I would like `foo` to be deleted in case of error. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
foo:
    perl -e 'die()' > $@ || [rm $@ -a true]
```

What is it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `perl -e 'die()' > $@ || rm $@`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't propagates `$?` of the first process.

Comment: Then `perl -e 'die()' > $@ || { rm $@; exit 1; }` (unless you need to propagate the exit status of the first process exactly)

Comment: The special variable `$@` should be quoted (eg. `perl -e 'die()' > "$@" || rm "$@"`.

Comment: @Leon `perl -e 'die()' > $@ || { rm $@; false;}` should work also and avoids exiting too fast

Comment: Work fine for me if I modify your command to `ls /tmp1 > $@ || rm $@`. Is it possible that the return value of `perl -e 'die()' > $@` always be true?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569228/can-a-makefile-execute-code-only-when-an-error-has-occurred

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU make can do that for you.

[Special Built-in Target Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets):

> `.DELETE_ON_ERROR`
>
> If `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` is mentioned as a target anywhere in the makefile, then make will delete the target of a rule if it has changed and its recipe exits with a nonzero exit status, just as it does when it receives a signal.

---

It is a general problem that creating a file is a non-atomic operation. And not always you can delete an incomplete or corrupted file on termination, for example, when the program is killed with `SIGKILL` or by the OOM-killer. In other words, all solutions involving removing the file are prone to failures.

The robust generic solution is:

1. Create the file with a temporary filename.
2. Once the file is complete and have correct permissions, rename it to the final name. [Renaming a file is an atomic operations in UNIX](https://rcrowley.org/2010/01/06/things-unix-can-do-atomically.html), as long as the file stays in the same filesystem.

E.g.:

```
foo:
    perl -e 'die()' > $@~
    mv --force $@~ $@
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me…

```
foo: 
    @perl -e 'die()' > $@ || { echo "removing $@ because exit code was $${?}"; rm $@; }
```

#### Output

```
Died at -e line 1.
removing foo because exit code was 255
```